# asp.NET intranet site: if I try to run multiple reports, one after the other, I get SQL permissions error on stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I inherited an old asp.NET site.  This site uses windows authentication and has several reports.  each report makes a separate call to different stored procedures on the SQL server.

If I go to the site and run 1 report, I can run any of the reports.  If I try to run 1 report then try to run another report, sometimes I get the error message below:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'XYZ', database 'ABC', schema 'dbo'

If I hit the back button then try to run any other report, I will get the same error message.  I have to close my browser and go back to the site, then it will allow me to run any other report, but only 1 report (if I try to run a second report, I get the same error message).

This happens most of the time.  Sometimes I can run all the reports without getting an error message, but most of the time I get the error message on the 2nd report I try to run.

I don't think this is a permissions issue, since I have permissions and can run all of the reports, I just have to close the browser after each report I run.  I don't know when this issue started or what changed to cause it to happen.  I am really at a loss and don't even know where to start.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's hard to tell you what the code is doing wrong if you don't show us what you're doing.

Comment: Since you still haven't provided any actual information to help I would start by looking at how your connections are being handled. This has a sort of smell to it like maybe connections are left open and causing issues. Make sure they are either in a using statement or explicitly being disposed.

Comment: Could this be some sort of a "lame" attempt at preventing users from running multiple reports at once?